# DocuSign API method envelopes.listStatusChanges doesn't show envelopes shared to my user

Tags: docusignapi

I'm calling listStatusChanges with an http GET similar to this:
.../restapi/v2/accounts//envelopes?from_date=&start_position=0&count=50

It works for envelopes owned by anyone when my current user has permission of DS Admin.
It works for envelopes owned by my current user when my user has permission of DS Sender.

However, I have certain users who have shared their envelopes mo my current user.  In the DocuSign user interface, I see these **Shared Envelopes**.  But this sharing seems to have no impact on this API call.  The shared envelopes are not visible unless I have DS Admin permission.

Is this working correctly?  Is it a bug?  Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: do you use this to look for envelopes? I would suggest a different endpoint in the v2.1 API instead to see if your issue is resolved. (https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/envelopes/search)

Comment: Thank you for responding, @InbarGazit.  However, the link you provided is to the same API method I am already using.  

As I said, I am using listStatusChanges GET with URL accounts/envelopes?....

Comment: I understand. Can you explain what you are trying to do? there may be another API method that can solve your issue.

Comment: What I am trying to do is get a list of envelopes that have experienced recent status changes.  I think that is exactly what this method is supposed to do.

Before changing code to try another DocuSign API method, I'd like to determine if this one is working as intended or if I've unearthed a bug.

Comment: you can do that with the other API I showed. You will get all envelopes and check their status.

Answer (score 2):

If you know other user's userId then you can use below API call to see that user's shared envelopes. You must specifically call that out in the request through the `user_id` parameter, and only one other user can be queried for per API call.

```
/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes?from_date=2019-07-15T08:00:00.000Z&user_id=87b00103-461d-487b-8928-1991dfdb8d20
```

where 87b00103-461d-487b-8928-1991dfdb8d20 is the userId of the other user whose envelopes you want to see.

Note the use of /v2.1/ in this call's URL. The /v2/ version of this call does not correctly respect Envelope Sharing, but /v2.1/ has corrected this issue and will not require the use of DS Admin permissions.

Comment: We wish to find a list of envelopes with status changes for any user.
As I've stated, we can do so when running as DSAdmin.  If that is "the answer", then I'll update our documentation and we'll run with this.

My question is whether this is how it is supposed to be.  It _seems_ that sharing envelopes should alleviate the need to use DSAdmin permission.

Answer (score 0):

I reached Drew M. in DocuSign Developer Support.  He provided this answer:

> I've tested this on my account, and it does look like that API call
>   doesn't correctly respect Sharing, so at this time it does require
>   Admin rights. I'll be filing a product issue about this, and I'll let
>   you know what I hear back.

Subsequently, Drew reported that this was in fact fixed in v2.1, per his comment below.

Comment: This issue is resolved in the /v2.1/ version of the API call. I've updated Amit's answer accordingly.

Comment: We all know the phrase, "trust, but verify", right?  I decided to test v2.1 today.  I found that, just like v2, it still doesn't return any shared envelopes unless it has DS Admin permission.  With that permission, it returns all envelopes (subject to date and other filters) regardless of sharing.

Comment: BTW: v2.1 adds several properties to the envelopes it returns, which may save an extra API call to get these details.  However, v2.1 returns no "envelopes" property at all if there are no envelopes returned, whereas v2 returned an empty array.  Be sure to null check "envelopes" if you upgrade to v2.1.

Comment: The v2.1 version of the call does change the behavior. Shared envelopes must be queried for specifically via the `user_id` parameter - they won't appear in the general list.